# How to manual commit do not recorverd offset already sent DLT through CommonErrorHandler

Tags: spring-kafka

A simple example is currently being made through the spring kafka.

If an exception occurs at the service layer, I want to commit the original offset after trying to retry and loading it into the dead letter queue.

However, the dead letter queue is loaded properly, but the original message remains in the kafka because the commit is not processed.

To show you my code, it is as follows.

- KafkaConfig.java

```java
...
 @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(kafkaListenerErrorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        return factory;
    }

    private CommonErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler() {
        DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(
            new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template, DEAD_TOPIC_DESTINATION_RESOLVER),
            new FixedBackOff(1000, 3));
       
        defaultErrorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        defaultErrorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(true);
        defaultErrorHandler.setResetStateOnRecoveryFailure(false);

        
        return defaultErrorHandler;
    }
...
```

- KafkaListener.java

```java
...
@KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC_NAME, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId = "stock-adjustment-0")
    public void subscribe(final String message, Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {

        log.info(String.format("Message Received : [%s]", message));

        StockAdjustment stockAdjustment = StockAdjustment.deserializeJSON(message);

        if(stockService.isAlreadyProcessedOrderId(stockAdjustment.getOrderId())) {
            log.info(String.format("AlreadyProcessedOrderId : [%s]", stockAdjustment.getOrderId()));
        } else {
            if(stockAdjustment.getAdjustmentType().equals("REDUCE")) {
                stockService.decreaseStock(stockAdjustment);
            }
        }
    ack.acknowledge(); // <<< does not work!
    }
...
```

- Stockservice.java

```java
...
        if(stockAdjustment.getQty() > stock.getAvailableStockQty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Stock decreased Request [decreasedQty: %s][availableQty : %s]", stockAdjustment.getQty(), stock.getAvailableStockQty()));
        }
...
```

At this time, when `RuntimeException` occur in the service layer as above, the DLT is issued through an `CommonErrorhandler` according to the Kafka setting.

[image]

However, after issuing the DLT, the original message remains in Kafka, so there is a need for a solution.

I looked it up and found that the setting I wrote is processed through `SeekUtils.seekOrRecover()`, and if it is not processed even if the maximum number of attempts is not processed, an exception occurs and the original offset is rolled back without processing a commit.

According to the document, it seems that the `AfterRollbackProcessor` handles rollback if it fails with the default value, but I don't know how to write the code to commit even if it fails.

**EDITED**

The above code and settings work normally.

I thought the **consumer lag** would occur, but when I judged the actual logic code(`SeekUtils.seekOrRecover()`) and checked the offset commit and lag, I confirmed that it works normally.

I think it was caused by my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records are never removed (until they expire), the consumer's committed offset is updated.

Use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to describe the group to see the committed offset for the failed record that was sent to the DLT.

Comment: I have been following the code since I posted the above question.

In fact, look at the internal logic of `SeekUtils.seeOrRecover()`, then i can see that it handles commitments to the original offset. 

**I judged that a consumer lag occurs, but as you said, the record itself is not deleted, but I think I misunderstood that a lag occurs and got confused. I understand the code above again and it works fine.**